# Simple Expression Language: how to get the ${routeId} in Apache Camel 2.10

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse, simple-el

How can I access the "routeId" in Apache Camel 2.10?

I see that the property exists from camel 2.11.

From [Simple Expression Langauge docs](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html)

```
${routeId}
String
Camel 2.11: Returns the id of the current route the Exchange is being routed.
```

Is there another easy hack available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you would need to do a little piece of code to get the route id. You can check the source code of Camel 2.11 onwards to see how Camel does it in that function.